# Updating state and changing route without re-rendering component twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js

probably a simple solution but drawing a blank. In my application i have a component that has a button that when clicked, it changes the state of the parent component while  pushing a new route.

```
const dayToggle = (date, day) => {    
            
            if (day != activeDay){
              setActiveDay(day) 
              Router.push(`?date=${date}`) 
            }

    }
```

This results in the child component being re-rendered twice, 1x through (setActiveDay) and 1x through router.push.

Is there a way to only render once. I've tried having activeday in a variable instead of state but after changing the route it sets it back to the default since its assigned at the top of the component.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried shallow routing? https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

Comment: _"Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods again"_ - shallow routing won't prevent the component re-rendering twice.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how the `activeDay` state and `data` query param are used, but have you considered either passing the `day` value through the query string, or deriving `activeDay` from the `date` value passed in the query param? Both ways would avoid having to call `setActiveDay(day)`.